# How many times my file has been downloaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, reports, download

I need to know how many times a file on a sharepoint.com site was downloaded.
So that I know how many people used my shared product.

Comment: What kind of file are you talking about? Is it a ZIP file? Did you share your file with external users?

Comment: Yes It is a zip file and the file is shared with anyone has the link

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this with a PDF file that I have uploaded into the "files" tab of a Teams of mine.

When hovering over the filename of that PDF file in SharePoint, I can directly see that there have been "22 views" of that file. When clicking on the "22 views" line of text, I can see some viewing statistics like views and unique visitors that have viewed the file.

"Viewed", I suppose, includes downloads of the file as well.

Comment: ...but thats a weekly view, and it only goes back 3 months....

Answer (score 0):

Auditing for Opening or downloading documents is not available for SharePoint Online because of storage and performance concerns.

However you can use Office 365 Security&Compliance center to find this information.

- Go to https://protection.office.com
- Sign in to Office 365 using your account
- Open Search > Audit log search:
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for your support. I can't find the Search tab. What do you think about this case?